# How to display a word randomly from list of other words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so i have an array of names like this

```
var names = ["Bob", "Aaron", "John"];
```

How would i have a line or lines of code that would randomly pick between all 3 of these names and display it? Would i use math.random()?

Comment: yes you need to use `math.random()`

Answer (score 6):

Since you have a collection of names rather than key value pairs it's better to use an array to store your names rather than a hash.

With an array, you can use Math.floor and Math.random to generate an index to look up in the names array.

```
names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)]
```