# Randomly selecting name from array

Tags: javascript

Ok so I have an array of names that are to be displayed on the page when the user hits the button "generate".

I can't get the names to show up on the screen.

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

```
<p id="textbox">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var names = {"Alex", "Alan", "Sean"};
var displayNames = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];

document.getElementById("textbox").innerHMTL = displaynames;
</script>
```

Comment: names isn't an array..its an object...put it in [] instead of {}

Comment: That is not an array or an object, that is an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644447/how-to-display-a-word-randomly-from-list-of-other-words/31644478#31644478

Answer (score 3):

1. Change the curly braces to square brackets:

   `var names = ["Alex", "Alan", "Sean"];`
2. Be consistent in capitalization.  `displayNames` is not the same as `displaynames`.
3. Change `innerHMTL` to `innerHTML`.

```js
var names = ["Alex", "Alan", "Sean"];
var displayNames = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];

document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = displayNames;
```

```html
<p id="textbox"></p>
```

Comment: it works now, but i need it to change each time the user presses a button, so i don't have to reload the page

Comment: You could post a new question showing your attempt, and you should get some good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many typos:

1. {} -> []
2. displaynames -> displayNames
3. innerHMTL -> innerHTML